# Support of polynomial distribution

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ What is supp$(\widehat{P})$ when $P$ viewed as a tempered distribution. Can supp$(\widehat{P})$ be the boundary of an sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think:
Let $P=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha},$ then 
$$\widehat{P}=\widehat{\Big(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}\Big)}=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}\widehat{x^{\alpha}}=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}\frac{\partial^{\alpha}\delta_0}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$$
Thus supp$(\widehat{P})\subset$ supp$(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}\frac{\partial^{\alpha}\delta_0}{\partial x^{\alpha}})\subset\,$ supp$(\delta_0)=\{0\}$

Comment: You forgot some harmless $i$ and some power of $2\pi$ but for the rest I agree with you.